# Equivalent static_asserts giving conflicting results for is_array<>

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding, universal-reference, forwarding-reference

In the following snippet, an static assert passes and the other one fails:

```cpp
template <class Rng> constexpr bool is_array(Rng&& r) {
  // int*** debug = r;  // uncomment this to debug r's type
  return std::is_array<Rng>{};
  // return std::is_array<decltype(r)>{};  // fails too
}

int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
static_assert(std::is_array<decltype(a)>{}, ""); // passes
static_assert(is_array(a), ""); // fails
```

Tip: Remove the comment to debug the type (it is correctly deduced to be `int [5]`).

Why is this? Tested on clang trunk.

I'd guess it has something to do with arrays decaying into pointers.. somehow.

Solution: use `std::remove_reference_t`, `Rng` will be `int (&)[5]`, this is a reference to an array, and not an array.

Xeo added:

```cpp
template<class> struct dump;
dump<decltype(r)>{};
```

will fail to compile and reveal the correct type of `r`.

The `int**** j = r;` produced a wrong error (saying can't assing `int[5]` to `int****`).

Comment: Try inserting a `remove_reference`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Makes sense and works, crap. Clang error message threw me off, it says couldn't assign `int [5`] to `int***` instead of `int (&)[5]` or similar.

Comment: Scott Meyers' trick for seeing the type of `T` is `template<class> class TD /* undefined */; TD<T> foo;`.

Comment: Should this question be closed now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `Rng` is `int (&)[5]` which is a reference to an array (and not an array) and hence `std::is_array` returns `false_type`.

One can remove the reference (e.g. using `std::remove_reference_t`) to make it work as you expected.